# 3D models not loading on android device, google chrome

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I have a website and the 3d models I made are not loading on chrome in android. However when scrolling down to a different 3d model in the website: some 3d balls, only one of the balls doesn't load.

I haven't tried much and am still searching for answers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.